# Is there any use for auto generated visual studio <meta> tags

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2005, meta-tags

We have an old project lying around with these `<meta>` tags in every page. This website is an intranet web application.

```
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio 7.0" />
<meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="C#" />
<meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript" />
<meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />
```

- Do they have any value or use?
- Is it safe to remove them?

I'm using VS2005 if that matters for the intellisense.

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/visual-studio-mete-tags-t1262568.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the `vs_defaultClientScript` and `vs_targetSchema` are used for intelisense. You can remove the other tags without any problems.

Answer (score 6):

They have no use for web clients (other then leaking information about your development environment and using up bandwidth) only for your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

On some machines it can cause slow loading of the page in IE 11, but it's not clear, on what it depends. Just one user in the office had problems - had to wait 5 - 10 seconds for loading the page, which other users saw immediately... on same Win 7 and IE 11. I removed 
    
and it's OK.